# How to turn back notifications for an app?

Tags: windows-10

[image]

So there was an app that showed notifications in the notifications tab, and I turned it off.
I want to turn it on again, but the app itself is not listed in the notification list.
Tried reinstalling it, but still, no notification is shown.
Is there a way to reset notifications totally, or any idea what could bring it back?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.Kindly check the notification area related GPO and registry key:

GPO: User Configuration-->Administrative Templates-->and Start Menu and Taskbar--->Hide the notification area

Registry:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
NoTrayItemsDisplay

2.As for reset Notification Area Icons, following link would be helpful:
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5662-reset-notification-area-icons-windows-10-a.html